# AppScript Google Sheets: Match Serial #s from checkout sheet to the main sheet then update cells in main sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fairly new to scripting and I've got my brain drained from doing this. I've tried searching for answers for weeks and still, my script fails to do what I intended it to do.

To explain clearly, this sheet is to be used as a simple checkout and inventory system where on checkout, the cashier will fill in the serial numbers of the products which will return details such as price, item name, category, availability using the vlookup function. This has been set and is working.

The problem I have is that on checkout payment, the cashier needs to update the main "INventory" sheet columns with details such as Client Name, Date of Purchase, Cashier Name, Payment method, as well as update status from "Available" to "Sold." Currently, these are done manually and are too time-consuming. I figure that this is possible using a script where the Cashier will just click a button and then will initiate the script to update the main INventory sheet.

I've read countless on how to go about this and has started a script (updateInventory) but the problem with this is that:

1. It's failing to update the appropriate cells
2. It takes too long and more often than not the script will terminate as the execution takes more than 5-6 minutes which is Google's time limit on scripts. The original sheet has > 5000 rows but I believe this won't be a problem by using arrays or objects and applying script optimization but I don't really know how to use them properly.

I'm including here a copy of the original sheet with fields and details redacted.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hWouvaOZ6R5pGZCPm6wYyeFHmSljvMr9hG9zhbFrTQ/edit#gid=2121597849
Note that most columns are hidden since it's irrelevant but I didn't delete them to represent the original as closely as possible.

Here's also the script that I've been working on and failing continuously:

```
function updateInventory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('OUT');
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('INventory');
  var sh1rg = sh1.getRange(7,4,sh1.getLastRow(),1);
  var sh2rg = sh2.getRange(3,11,sh2.getLastRow(),1);
  var sh1sn = sh1rg.getValues();
  var sh2sn = sh2rg.getValues();
  var clientrg = sh1.getRange(1,3); 
  var client = clientrg.getValue();
  var cashierrg = sh1.getRange(38,4);
  var cashier = cashierrg.getValue();
  var daterg = sh1.getRange(2,3)
  var date = daterg.getValue ()
  var paymentrg = sh1.getRange(3,3)
  var payment = daterg.getValue ()
  for(var i=0;i<sh2sn.length-1;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<sh1sn.length;j++) {
      if(sh2sn[i][0] == sh1sn[j][0]) {
      sh2.getRange(i+2,31).setValue(date)
      sh2.getRange(i+2,23).setValue("Sold");
      sh2.getRange(i+2,35).setValue(cashier);
      sh2.getRange(i+2,30).setValue(client);
      sh2.getRange(i+2,33).setValue("YES");
      sh2.getRange(i+2,34).setValue(payment);
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I really hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your sample script, it seems that the values in the sheet of `INventory` starts from row 3. But in your script, `sh2.getRange(i+2,31)` is used. In your script, an error occurs at the row 2 because of the data validation rule.
- In your question, you say `update status from "Available" to "Sold."` and the column on "STATUS" is the column "R". But in your script, "Solid" is put to the column "W".

  - I thought that these might be the reason of your 1st issue.
- And, `setValue` is used every row in the loop.

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your 2nd issue.
- In your goal, it seems that the values of `"Sold",client,date,"YES",payment,cashier` are put in the discontinuous 6 columns of `R,AD,AE,AG,AH,AI`, respectively. So in this case, I would like to propose to put the values using the range list.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for(var i=0;i<sh2sn.length-1;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<sh1sn.length;j++) {
    if(sh2sn[i][0] == sh1sn[j][0]) {
    sh2.getRange(i+2,31).setValue(date)
    sh2.getRange(i+2,23).setValue("Sold");
    sh2.getRange(i+2,35).setValue(cashier);
    sh2.getRange(i+2,30).setValue(client);
    sh2.getRange(i+2,33).setValue("YES");
    sh2.getRange(i+2,34).setValue(payment);
      break
    }
  }
}
```

To:

```
var objFromOUT = sh1sn.reduce((o, [d]) => {
  if (d.toString() != "") o[d] = true;
  return o;
}, {});
var putValues = {
  R: {ranges: [], value: "Sold"},
  AD: {ranges: [], value: client},
  AE: {ranges: [], value: date},
  AG: {ranges: [], value: "YES"},
  AH: {ranges: [], value: payment},
  AI: {ranges: [], value: cashier},
};
sh2sn.forEach(([v], i) => {
  if (v.toString() != "" && objFromOUT[v]) {
    Object.keys(putValues).forEach(k => putValues[k].ranges.push(`${k}${i + 3}`));
  }
});
Object.entries(putValues).forEach(([_,v]) => sh2.getRangeList(v.ranges).setValue(v.value));
```

- In this modified script, you can adjust the put values and the column at `putValues`. In the current stage, for example, `R: {ranges: [], value: "Sold"}` means that the value of `"Solid"` is put to the column "R".

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Comment: Hi, Tanaike! First, I want to thank you for taking the time to review the problem that I'm spending days on without clear results. Second and most importantly, IT WORKED PERFECTLY!! I wouldn't have been able to figure this out even if I'll spend months on it. Frankly, if it wasn't spelled out like the way you did it, I imagine I wouldn't even able to make it work. Thank you very much! Hope you have a good one. Cheers!

Comment: @J Carpo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. THank you, too.